# Examples of Riemannian manifolds which are both complete and geodesically convex?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

What are some examples of a Riemannian manifold which is both complete and [geodesically convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_convexity)?  An obvious example is $R^n$.  An open hemisphere of $S^n$ is geodesically convex but not complete.  I don't believe hyperbolic space is geodesically convex, although I might be wrong.

Edit 1: We say Riemannian manifold $M$ is geodesically convex if given any two points in $M$, there is a unique minimizing geodesic contained within $M$ that joins those two points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any complete simply connected manifold with negative curvature is geodesically connected. The hyperbolic space is geodesically connected. The reason is that such manifolds have neither conjugate points nor focal points and consequently is simply geodesically convex.